# Crashlytics Dashboard only showing debug application

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I used the Crashlytics Plugin for Android Studio to add the important code for crashlytics initialization to my application.

Now I can only see the debug-build in the fabric dashboard
and can't make it to remove this application or add the realease build to fabric.

In my Application class i only initialize Fabric on release build.

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

and disable it in debug build in the gradle file.

```
debug {
    ...
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

When I use the plugin and add a new app I can see the release build with a yellow checkmark in front (I guess it means that the app is configured correctly)

How can i remove the debug application and add the release one to crashlytics?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you make the same code changes to your released build or do a build and run of your app in a release build, you should see your app added.

Comment: Hey Mike, a combination of computer restart + uninstall of release build on phone + other phone + clean project + run of the release build worked finally. Don't know what was the problem. Many thanks for your help!